# Version control for user created text content

Tags: svn, version-control, text, user-data

*Problem*: I am developing a website where users will create, edit and sell stories (basically text files). I want to implement a user-friendly version control for their texts (more or less like Google Docs). I am **not looking for a Wiki**, I am rather looking for a VCS solution that can be integrated in a website where version control is only one aspect (for instance, I have my own editors, with web, Desktop and iOS versions).

*Design details*: In my design I would like to be able to deal with 50k users, each with an average of 4 stories (text files) with 100kb each. Their stories would be automatically committed at least every 30 minutes or so. I am worried about the possible overhead and delays frequent creation and deletion and commit of changes of thousands of stories and hundred of accounts. Another concern I have is vulnerability of the data to corruption. Finally there is also the problem of practicality. For the later it may help to know I am programming my server web interfaces mainly in Python 2.7 using Django 1.3. With the above in mind I have the following questions:

1. Supposing I use subversion (which I am familiar with, but never used in such scale). Which of the options below is better?
  1. create a separate project for each user;
  2. create a separate folder for each user, all in a same huge project;
  3. create separate files for each user all in the same folder and project (to avoiding processing thousands of .svn headers).
2. Supposing I do not use subversion. Which other VCS do you recommend (Git? Mercurial? ...) and with what kind of setup (in the molds of question above)? Please, briefly explain why.

Comment: Isn't what you are looking for a wiki? Anyway, nothing to do with programming, so voting to close.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I am not really looking for a wiki. I am sorry if the way I described the problem made it sound like so. I am actually programming a website, where users will create and sell stories, so editing is only one aspect of it. I want my users to be able to rewind back and compare their changes, and let people who are reading their stories (potential buyers) to be able to check recent changes. The programming problem is there in the sense that I must choose the appropriate version control sub-system to interface with in the server side (either that or maybe implement one myself).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a wiki with strict security settings, so that each user can only see their own wiki pages? A popular wiki project is [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

Comment: I am not looking for a Wiki like MediaWiki because I want to keep full control of my end user's experience when editing and reading the stories (having my own customized editor and reader). I do not discard the possibility of using a similar backend -- I will try to have a look into how MediaWiki implements version control. Your answer gives a nice direction of research. Unfortunately I do not have reputation enough to vote it up yet. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you must go with a VCS, I think you would have much better luck with a distributed VCS like [git](http://git-scm.com/) or [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).  The repositories are lightweight and you could easily create one per user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am looking for a VCS indeed, but I would appreciate some advice on how to setup the problem. I understand you recommend using Git or Mercurial with one project per user, right? I've redesigned the question to be more specific, please have a look if you find some time. Unfortunately I do not have reputation enough to vote your answer up yet. Cheers.

Comment: Hmmm...If you do go with SVN, I would avoid any of the "all in one huge project" designs for scaling reasons.  You'll have a lot more flexibility for future growth with a project-per-user scheme.  The reason I suggested git or mercurial is that creating repositories is cheap.  Reading more, they also might be good choice for keeping content in sync in your future multi-device scenario and they don't require an internet connection for commits.  Here's a quick intro to DVCS plus an hg quickstart: http://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/.  Good luck!